# IF THEN Statement in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to convert the below SAS code to snowflake

```
IF CUSTOMER_NUMBER = 1 THEN SEQ = 1;
ELSE IF FIRST.CUSTOMER_NUMBER = 0 THEN SEQ = SEQ+1;

IF TRANSACTION_CODE = '41' THEN REVERSE_SEQ = SEQ - 1;
```

Comment: HI try this if (CUSTOMER_NUMBER = 1) then SEQ := 1 else SEQ := SEQ+1; end if;     The same way you could write for the TRANSACTION_CODE  condition, unless you want both to be one, if else

Comment: this syntax didn't work with me and generated error message saying (unexpected THEN). Any suggestions please?

Comment: Which of the coding languages that Snowflake works with are you trying to use - SQL Scripting, Javascript, etc? Are you trying to write a stored procedure, a function, or what? What is the complete piece of code that you are trying to re-create?

Comment: I'm trying to convert my sas code to snowflake because we are going to leave SAS and use Snowflake instead. I'm trying to write a stored procedure. The code is too long and there is not enough space to post it. I just need help regarding the IF THEN statement.

Comment: Are any of the values you're testing here coming from a cursor (CUSTOMER_NUMBER or FIRST.CUSTOMER_NUMBER)?  If so, make sure you have a local variable defined to assign the fetched result before doing a logical compare in the IF construct.

Comment: As already mentioned if you are undertaking a migration project, at the very minimum you need to know which language you are migrating to. If you _do_ know that language then the very minimum you can do when asking a SO question is indicating what it is

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL as your stored proc language, see below code snippet.  Use "=" for compare, and ":=" for assignment.  Block your your work with BEGIN / END, and IF constructs with END IF (note the nested versions below).

If you're using cursors, you will need to define a local variable in the declare section and assign it the fetched value, which you can then use that local variable for both compares and assignments.  See the examples in the Snowflake documentation here for more details: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-snowflake-scripting.html

```
create or replace procedure test (customer_number integer)
    returns integer not null
    language sql
    as 
declare 
seq integer;

begin seq := 0;
if (customer_number = 1) then seq := 1;
    else if (customer_number = 0) then seq := seq + 10;
    end if;
end if;
    return seq;
end;
```

call test (1) returns the integer 1, call test(0) returns the integer 10.

Answer (score 0):

What Jim suggested should work perfectly. Also, you might consider Javascript, Python or any other available type of Snowflake functions depending of your use cases.

It's a mind shift and a learning curve if you are coming from SQL based languages (Oracle, SQL Serve, MySQL, etc.), but definitely worth of trying as they provide more flexibility (error handling, dynamic sql, etc.) comparing to SQL type fn, which have many limitations when it comes to more advanced code or logic.

Please, find an example below. Also, I've added else part only for demo purposes.

- [Snowflake JavaScript stored procedures](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-javascript)
- [SQL-Java Data Type Mappings](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf-stored-procedure-data-type-mapping#label-javascript-supported-snowpark-types)

```js
create or replace procedure test_js_if(p_customer_number float)
returns float not null
language javascript
EXECUTE AS OWNER
as
$$  
    //declare variables
    var seq = 0;
    var customer_number = P_CUSTOMER_NUMBER; //sp arguments are case sensitive in javascript portion of the procedure and require UPPERCASE
    
    if(customer_number == 1){
      seq = 1;
    } else if(customer_number == 0){
      seq += 10;
    } else {
      seq = -1;
    }   
    
    return seq;
    $$
    ;

//Call functions

call test_js_if(1); //returns: 1
call test_js_if(0); //returns: 10
call test_js_if(10); //returns: 10
```